# ActiveXObject run does not return (shell)

Tags: javascript, shell, exec, activex

I am running a shell script from a JavaScript environment using ActiveXObject. Everything works just fine if I do not include any parameters in the run function:

```
var x = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
x.Run("%comspec% /K dir")
alert("I am here!")
```

According to the documentation, "The Run method also accepts a Boolean value as a third parameter that determines whether the script pauses until the called program is finished running or instead continues with the next command in the script. If this value is set to False (the default), the Run method simply issues the command to run the program but does not check to ensure that the program actually ran. If the third parameter is set to True, the script will wait for the program to finish running, return the integer exit code provided by the program, and then continue with the next line of the script."

I tried to use both

```
x.Run("%comspec% /K dir"), 1, True
alert("I am here!")
```

and

```
x.Run("%comspec% /K dir"), 1, False
alert("I am here!")
```

but my code always hangs. The alert is never displayed. What am I doing wrong? (I need to use the third argument = true in my code)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the arguments in the parenthesis:

```
x.Run("%comspec% /K dir", 1, true);
```

Currently your script uses a couple of comma operators. At first it executes the `Run` method, evaluates `1`, and finally breaks to an undefined variable name (`True`). JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: Problem fixed! I was using True instead of true...
Thanks!